# How to get only an list object that is inside another JSON object?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, deserialization

I am using an external API via Feign client in my study project, and it returns a lot of data that I don't need. Therefore, I want to access only an object that is inside another JSON object.

I tried to do this using JsonSetter, but it didn't work out very well. This is my DTO:

```java
public record AgendamentoResponse(
    @DatePattern
    @JsonSetter("data.workschedule.scheduleDate")
    LocalDate dataAgendamento,
    @JsonSetter("data.workschedule.timeslotDescription")
    String periodoLabel,
    @JsonSetter("data.workschedule.timeslotStart")
    String periodoInicio,
    @JsonSetter("data.workschedule.timeslotEnd")
    String periodoFim,
    @JsonSetter("data.workschedule.category")
    String categoria
) {
}
```

this is the API response:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "1;2022-11-29",
    "transactionId": “some id“,
    "data": {
        "workschedule": [
            {
                "scheduleDate": "2024-01-20",
                "timeslotDescription": "08:00 - 12:00",
                "timeslotStart": "08:00:00",
                "timeslotEnd": "12:00:00",
                "category": "CLASSE1"
            },
            {
                "scheduleDate": "2024-01-20",
                "timeslotDescription": "12:00 - 15:00",
                "timeslotStart": "12:00:00",
                "timeslotEnd": "15:00:00",
                "category": "CLASSE1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and this is my client:

```java
    @GetMapping("appointments/workschedules")
    List<AgendamentoResponse> consultarAgendamentosDisponiveis(
        @RequestHeader(name = "X-QueryString", required = false) String partyAccountId,
        @SpringQueryMap AgendamentoParams params);
```

is there anyway i can map this response? i allways get this error:

```
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do something like this:

```
public class WorkSchedule {
    private LocalDate scheduleDate;
    private String timeslotDescription;
    private String timeslotStart;
    private String timeslotEnd;
    private String category;

    public WorkSchedule(LocalDate scheduleDate, String timeslotDescription, String timeslotStart, String timeslotEnd, String category) {
        this.scheduleDate = scheduleDate;
        this.timeslotDescription = timeslotDescription;
        this.timeslotStart = timeslotStart;
        this.timeslotEnd = timeslotEnd;
        this.category = category;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Create the Data class like this:

```
public class Data {
    @JsonProperty("workschedule")
    private List<WorkSchedule> workSchedules;

    // getters and Setters
}
```

Create a record for AgendamentoResponse:

```
public record AgendamentoResponse(Data data) {
}
```

Change your client:

```
@GetMapping("appointments/workschedules")
AgendamentoResponse consultarAgendamentosDisponiveis(
    @RequestHeader(name = "X-QueryString", required = false) String partyAccountId,
    @SpringQueryMap AgendamentoParams params);
```

Make your call:

```
AgendamentoResponse response = httpClientService.consultarAgendamentosDisponiveis(partyAccountId, params);
```

Once it returns the response just parse your data.

Comment: didnt work, workSchedules is always null :(

Comment: do you have anything in the console? any errors?